# Getting match results in REST API GET method

Tags: rest

We onboard local businesses on our app platform. Our mobile client app is making a query into Google places API and getting a list of nearby places. Now the client needs to send the IDs and REFs of those places to our server and see if any of those places are onboard on our app platform. Our server will check in the database for a match for those IDs and REFs, and the resultset will tell the "onboard status" of each place as true/false back to the client.

I was thinking I should implement this using GET method, because POST or any other verb does not describe what I want to do. When using GET, I cannot put stuff in the body. So how do I pass the entire list of JSON objects in the GET method URI? Does below sound OK?

GET /placestatus?placelist=[{ID:'idOfPlace1', REF:'refOfPlace1},{ID:'idOfPlace2', REF:'refOfPlace2},{ID:'idOfPlace3', REF:'refOfPlace2}]

Answer (score 0):

A GET won't work for you - you may run into URL length limitations.  What you are doing isn't exactly a GET, either.  You're actually passing information that needs to be processed, after which your server will return some information.  It's safer to use a POST and still makes sense within the definition and context of what you are doing.